# math operation on a second column

Tags: text-processing

Suppose my original file looks like this:

```
            N O D E   O U T P U T

THE FOLLOWING TABLE IS PRINTED FOR NODES BELONGING TO NODE SET NSET_OUTPUT
   NODE FOOT-   NT11     
        NOTE

      3       20.00     
     11       20.00     
   1003       23.75     
   1011       23.75     
   2003       27.52     
   2011       27.52     
   3003       31.30     
   3011       31.30     
   4003       35.08
```

I need to produce a second file but just with the values on second column multiplied by 100. How could I get this?

Comment: "multiplied by 100" is synonym to "remove the dot in the second column", right? Or can there be numbers with only one or more than two digits after the period?

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou [ and ] are literal in the replacement part of the substitution.

Comment: Is this output from Abaqus? Why not modify the job to print this in the corrected format instead?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to preserve the field widths and formats of the numeric data block, I'd suggest something like

```
awk '
  $1 ~ /[0-9]+/ && $2 ~ /[-+0-9.]+/ {
    $0 = sprintf("%6d%12.2f", $1, 100*$2)
  } 1
' file
```

Ex.

```
$ awk '$1 ~ /[0-9]+/ && $2 ~ /[-+0-9.]+/ {$0 = sprintf("%6d%12.2f", $1, 100*$2)} 1' file
            N O D E   O U T P U T

THE FOLLOWING TABLE IS PRINTED FOR NODES BELONGING TO NODE SET NSET_OUTPUT
   NODE FOOT-   NT11     
        NOTE

     3     2000.00
    11     2000.00
  1003     2375.00
  1011     2375.00
  2003     2752.00
  2011     2752.00
  3003     3130.00
  3011     3130.00
  4003     3508.00
```

Comment: the OP wanted only values on second column multiplied by 100 but not the content of entire file..

Comment: WHAT IF DECIMAL NUMBERS WERE LOCATED ALSO IN THE FIRST COLUMN? i tried to divide the first column by 10 , but it did not was successful.:awk '{if(/^ *[0-9\.]+ *[0-9\.]+ *$/) {var=$1*0.1; print var, $2;} else { print $0 }}' file

Comment: i ALSO TRIED:  awk '$1 ~ /[0-9]+/ && $2 ~ /[-+0-9.]+/ {$0 = sprintf("%6d%10.4f", 0.1*$1, $2)} 1' file.... but it did not shows the decimal positions in the first column

Comment: @AndrésF `%d` is an integer format specifier - if you want floating point you will need to change it to something like `%6.2f`. See `man 3 printf` for details of the available format specifiers.

Answer (score 1):

I'd choose to interpret the request as producing an output that consists solely of the numbers in the second column, multiplied by 100.

This assumes that the header is static and always six lines long.  It will be ignored.

```
$ awk 'FNR > 6 { print 100*$2 }' <infile
2000
2000
2375
2375
2752
2752
3130
3130
3508
```

The condition `FNR > 6` will trigger the block that multiplies and outputs the second field when at least six lines have been read.

If you don't know how long the header is, you may instead of `FNR > 6` use `$2 ~ /^-?[0-9.]+$/` which is a *naive* way of testing whether the second field is a floating point number, optionally signed ("an optional `-` followed by only digits and dots").

Comment: and what if I do not know how many lines should be read (more than 6, for example) in order to start with the columns of numbers (and print all of them)?

Comment: @AndrésF See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that your output is saved in a file called 'outfile', here's another solution - although a warning is that it doesn't preserve the formatting of the columns with numerical data.

```
awk '{if(/^ *[0-9\.]+ *[0-9\.]+ *$/) {var=$2*100; print $1,var;} else { print $0 }}' outfile
```

Comment: A dot is literal within `[...]`, as is backslash. So `[\.]` would match a backslash or a dot.